# Can't create notebook instance in amazon sagemaker

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sagemaker

I'm newbie of aws sagemaker. I'm trying to create notebook instance in aws console but the response is failed. Details error is: "Unable to create encrypted EBS volume. Check if the KMS key exists. Invalid arn (Service: AWSKMS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: NotFoundException;". Can you help me fix this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Can you please share what is the command line you are trying to use?

Comment: This is image of error https://imgur.com/a/aZ4VXF4. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Set the encryption to “No Encryption“ if you don’t have a valid ARN of an KMS key.

Answer (score 0):

Check the region the key was created in versus the region that SageMaker is using. For me, the key management page was defaulting to the East region while SageMaker was defaulting to the West region.

Comment: Thank you for your support. It's exactly my problem. When I changed region from Oregon to East, I can create normally.

Comment: I'm glad that worked for you! Can you accept the answer as correct?